# SQL trigger updating duration when given two timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Here is the table

```
 create table call(
 id varchar(5),
 start_time timestamp,
 end_time timestamp,
 duration INTERVAL DAY(5) TO SECOND(3),
 primary key(id)
 );
```

And the trigger:

```
 create or replace TRIGGER DURATION 
 BEFORE INSERT ON call
 for each row
 BEGIN
 select  end_time - start_time into :new.duration from dual;
 END;
```

so that it could work like this when doing insertion

```
 insert into call values(111,'2015-04-21 15:42:23','2016-11-03 18:32:47',null);
```

It's saying that the end_time is invalid identifier. I do realize I might need a sequence or something to make the end_time be referred to the specific row I am inserting, but I am not sure what to put there.

Comment: Please include an example of the insert statement with values that cause this condition to occur.

Comment: Also, which database is this?  Product name and version, please.

Comment: Thanks! I've edit the post. And it's for Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this change for the timestamp calculation:

```
select :new.end_time - :new.start_time into :new.duration from dual;
```

I suspect that qualifying the `end_time` and `start_time` columns as coming from the :new row may be necessary to do this correctly.

One additional point is that the INSERT statement should probably include the column names associated with the values.  This should also allow you to omit the 'duration', since it's specifically calculated in this trigger.

Consider this instead:

```
 insert into call (id, start_time, end_time) values(111,'2015-04-21 15:42:23','2016-11-03 18:32:47');
```

Hard lessons learned after making schema updates that suddenly break INSERT statements that had previously worked.  Worse, sometimes the INSERT doesn't actually fail, but silently goes about doing the wrong thing.